# SQL not working when I add the LIMIT keyword to it

Tags: php, mysql, sql, limit

Can't get my SQL `LIMIT` to work:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url, code, count FROM zipit WHERE uid='".$uid."' LIMIT '".$this_page_first_result."','".$results_per_page."'");
```

Comment: And what do your variables `$this_page_first_result` and `$results_per_page` map out to?

Comment: Dont wrap it in quotes its `LIMIT 1,1` not `LIMIT '1','1'` also fix your SQL injections before its too late.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you've got your query written translates to:

```
SELECT url , 
       code , 
       count 
FROM   zipit 
WHERE  uid='uid1234' 
LIMIT  '123','50'
```

The single quotes are invalid for your [`LIMIT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/limit-optimization.html) clause. . .

What you should use is:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT url,code,count 
                           FROM zipit 
                           WHERE uid='".$uid."' 
                           LIMIT ".$this_page_first_result.",".$results_per_page);
```

---

> LIMIT takes one or two numeric arguments, which must both be
>   nonnegative integer constants, with these exceptions:
>
> Within prepared statements, LIMIT parameters can be specified using ?
>   placeholder markers.
>
> Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables.
>
> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the
>   first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of
>   rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1)

Answer (score 0):

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url, code, count FROM zipit WHERE uid=$uid LIMIT $this_page_first_result,$results_per_page");

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT url, code, count FROM zipit WHERE uid='".$uid."' LIMIT ".$this_page_first_result.", ".$results_per_page);
```